# Setting properties for table and cell in RichTextctrl

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I am able to write a Table on RichTextctrl using RichTextctrl WriteTable Method.

https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl.html#wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl.WriteTable

```
def AddTable( self, event ):
    self.table=self.rtc.WriteTable(3,4)
```

Image: [Table_Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPWFx.jpg)

but, unable to set table and cell properties and also to identify the selected cells or tables in the RichTextctrl. Any example on this is helpful.Thanks in advance.

wxPython 4.0.0a1(Alpha version)

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue; but some example code
you would have to have your function return the table object self.table
have

```
import wx
import wx.richtext as rtc
```

assuming you are doing this in a class

```
columncount = self.table.GetColumnCount()
rowcount = self.table.GetRowCount()
```

## to get a specific cell here 2,3

```
self.myCell = self.table.GetCell(row=2, col=2)
```

## now to write to that cell -> has to be a string

```
self.myCell.AddParagraph("new stuff goest here")
```

## and to get text from the table-cell; indexed for which line of text you want

```
self.myCellText = self.myCell.GetParagraphText(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

def create_table(self):

```
xlist = []
xlist.append({'desc': 'blabla blabla', 'amt': 5, 'prc': 2.50})    
xlist.append({'desc': 'blabla blabla', 'amt': 5, 'prc': 2.50})    
xlist.append({'desc': 'blabla blabla', 'amt': 5, 'prc': 2.50})    
xlist.append({'desc': 'blabla blabla', 'amt': 5, 'prc': 2.50})    
xlist.append({'desc': 'blabla blabla', 'amt': 5, 'prc': 2.50})    
xlist.append({'desc': 'blabla blabla', 'amt': 5, 'prc': 2.50})    
table = self.ctrl.WriteTable(len(xlist), 3)    
for pos, cont in enumerate(xlist):    
    # Description
    cell = table.GetCell(row=pos, col=0)     
    prg = cell.GetParagraphAtLine(0)    
    prg.InsertText(1, str(cont['desc']))    
    prg.SetAttributes(self.set_alignment(prg, "left"))    
    cell.SetBasicStyle(self.set_colwidth(cell, 460))    
    cell.UpdateRanges()    
    # Amount
    cell = table.GetCell(row=pos, col=1)
    prg = cell.GetParagraphAtLine(0)
    prg.InsertText(1, str(cont['amt']))
    prg.SetAttributes(self.set_alignment(prg, "right"))
    cell.SetBasicStyle(self.set_colwidth(cell, 40))
    cell.UpdateRanges()
    # Price
    cell = table.GetCell(row=pos, col=2)
    prg = cell.GetParagraphAtLine(0)
    prg.InsertText(1, str(cont['prc']))
    prg.SetAttributes(self.set_alignment(prg, "right"))
    cell.SetBasicStyle(self.set_colwidth(cell, 60))
    cell.UpdateRanges()
```

def set_colwidth(self, cell, width):

```
dim_atr = rt.TextAttrDimension()
dim_atr.SetValue(width)
dim_atr.SetUnits(rt.TEXT_ATTR_UNITS_PIXELS)
size_atr = rt.TextAttrSize()
size_atr.SetWidth(dim_atr)
box_atr = rt.TextBoxAttr()
box_atr.SetSize(size_atr)
cell_atr = cell.GetBasicStyle()
cell_atr.SetTextBoxAttr(box_atr)
return cell_atr
```

def set_alignment(self, prg, ori):

```
attr = prg.GetAttributes()
if ori == "left":
    attr.SetAlignment(wx.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT)
    attr.SetLeftIndent(16)
elif ori == "right":
    attr.SetAlignment(wx.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_RIGHT)
    attr.SetRightIndent(16)
return attr
```